# Autocomplete JQuery in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a text box to enter city name. when I start typing the city name I want to to display suggestions to select. I am currently using phonegap to build the app.

Input textbox

```
<input type="text" class="input-text full-width" id = "city">
<input type ="hidden" id ="city_id" name ="city_id">
```

My jQuery Script

```
      //Load all Cities
    $(document).ready(function getCities(){       


var token = data;
alert(token);
    $( "input#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://seneruat.cloudapp.net/api/v1/searchCities?access_token="+token+"&q="+request.term ,
          dataType: "json",         
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.data, function( item ) {
              return {
                id: item.city_id ,
                label: item.city ,
                value: item.city
              }
            }));
          },
          error: function( data ) {
            alert('Error');
          }

        });
      },
      select: function (event, ui) {
        //console.log(ui);
        var id = ui.item.id;
        //alert(id);
        $('#city_id').val(id);
      },
       minLength: 2,
    }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.ui-autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<li "+ "class="+item.value + ">" + item.label + "</li>" ) 
            .appendTo( ul );
    };

     });
```

Can someone kindly suggest me how to get this done..
I want it to auto complete the cities when I start typing.
Any kind of help is appreciated..